# Set an EVP_PKEY from EC raw points, PEM or DER in both OpenSSL 1.1.1 and 3.0.x

Tags: c, openssl, elliptic-curve

I want to write some code that works against OpenSSL 1.1.1 and 3.0.x and future versions.

The code should set an EVP_PKEY to a particular EC key pair from either the points, DER or PEM. I don't really care which, because I know how to convert between them.

EVP_PKEY_fromdata() seems like the way to do it in 3.0.x, but it is not supported in 1.1.1.

Comment: There is no language tag, you want to solve it in C?

Comment: Yes. I knew I was missing a tag. Now I know which one. :-)

Comment: Most functions in 1.1.x are still supported in 3.0.x, although they may be deprecated.  So write code that works on 1.1.x and it should still work on 3.0.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an ECC 'keypair' from 'points' (in OpenSSL or anywhere). You can create a *public* key from *one* point plus the 'curve' (or more exactly parameter-set); for the Bernstein et al XDH schemes you use one coordinate (X) of the point instead of the whole point. To create a *private* key or keypair you must have the private key value, a scalar which is not a point or even a coordinate, and the 'curve'. (In proper mathematics an elliptic curve of the type used in crypto consists of an underlying finite field aka Galois field, with order either a sufficiently large prime or a sufficiently large power of two, plus a two-variable equation over that field in a standard form such as Weierstrass or Edwards which defines a set of points each having X,Y coordinates in the underlying field, plus a binary operation conventionally notated as addition over those points plus a special value called the point at infinity used as the additive identity, forming a finite cyclic group. However, to use such a curve in crypto we must also have a defined 'base' or generator point (or for XDH an X-coordinate defining a point together with its inverse), plus the order of the (sub)group generated by that base point (etc) under the curve operation, and its 'cofactor' relative to the full-group order; in some cases we also have information about how the curve was selected, and in most cases we also have associated identifier(s). Nonpedantic crypto people now generally use 'curve' to mean the combination of these. Although in principle applications and systems could define their own parameters=curves for ECC, as many did and do for non-elliptic DSA and DH, practically everyone uses curves specified by a standards organization which can be accessed by an identifier, such as 'P-256' and 'P-384' for the most commonly used curves identified by NIST (so far -- SP800-186 now in draft plans to add 25519 and 448, which are becoming about as common) and recommended by NSA, rather than specifying the extensive details of the underlying field, equation, basepoint, etc.)

For 'traditional' EC as defined by X9 using Weierstrass-form curves, OpenSSL supports several ASN.1 (external) representations for private keys and one for public keys, each in either 'DER' (binary) or PEM-style. For the Bernstein curves it supports one or two (depending how you count) private key and one public key, ditto. Specifically

- for public key (for both ECC and other algorithms) it uses the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure defined in X.509 and repeated in PKIX; for X9-type curves this contains data defined by X9 and repeated in [RFC3279 2.3.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3279#section-2.3.5) updated and modified by [RFC5480 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5480#section-2) while for Bernstein curves **will add later**.

  OpenSSL calls this format PUBKEY. It can be read into EVP_PKEY by `d2i_PUBKEY[_bio|fp]` for DER and `PEM_read[_bio]_PUBKEY` for PEM. It can also be read into an algorithm-specific `EC_KEY` by similar `EC_PUBKEY` routines and that `EC_KEY` then used to build `EVP_PKEY`, but why bother?
- for private key for X9-style only OpenSSL supports the algorithm-specific format defined in https://www.secg.org SEC1 appendix C and repeated in [RFC5915](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5915) read from DER by `d2i_ECPrivateKey[]` into `EC_KEY` and used to build `EVP_PKEY` similar to the above.
- for private key for all curves OpenSSL supports the generic PKCS8 format(s) defined in [RFC5208](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208) which includes an unencrypted and a password-encrypted version, read from DER by respectively `d2i_PrivateKey[]` and `d2i_PKCS8PrivateKey{}`.
- for private key in PEM there is only one group of routines `PEM_read[]_PrivateKey` which can handle both unencrypted and encrypted PKCS8 (distinguished by PEM label) and for X9-style unencrypted and PEM-encrypted SEC1 (distinguished by PEM label and headers).

If you don't have (and don't want to convert to or construct) one of these ASN.1 representations, the alternative is to create your key(s) 'by hand'.

For X9-style, this uses the `EC_GROUP` and `EC_KEY` internal (i.e. C-API) structures which respectively describe a curve as above and contain a public-key or key-pair on such a curve. If you are using a standard curve known to OpenSSL, you can get the `EC_GROUP` by calling `EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name` and use it to build an `EC_KEY`, or simply call `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name`. Note the 'name' here is not a true name like 'secp256k1' but OpenSSL's 'nid' -- an OpenSSL-assigned `int` that encodes a name (or if applicable both a full name and a short/abbreviated name) and corresponding X.509 object identifier (OID); see `OBJ_txt2nid` and related routines. If you want a custom/explicit curve it's quite a bit more complicated, and I'm not going into that unless you specify exactly what information you (will) have. Then call `EC_KEY_set_{private,public}_key` as applicable, for public key after parsing or converting the point data if necessary. Finally use the `EC_KEY` to build `EVP_PKEY`.

For Bernstein curves, create the `EVP_PKEY` directly with `EVP_PKEY_new_raw_{private,public}_key` by specifying the scheme; XDH and EdDSA and 25519 and 448 are treated as separate algorithms in OpenSSL, although the XDH and EdDSA forms of each curve are mathematically equivalent, because they are represented and implemented differently.

Comment: It was d2i_PrivateKey() that solved it for me. I put the RFC 5915 key bits in a static const C variable and imported it.

I can't use the EC_KEY stuff because it is slated for deprecation.

I knew a lot of the general stuff you wrote out already, but it still very helpful. Thank you!